# negative match in google analytics funnel (for use in shopify store)

Tags: regex, google-analytics, shopify, regex-lookarounds

I am setting up a conversion funnel in Google Analytics and want to capture all product collection pages for my Shopify store. To do this, I want to match everything with this pattern: *^/collections/.** but I also need to exclude everything with this pattern:

^/collections/.*****/products/.*

The reason being that collection(product category) pages follow this structure:
/collections/[collection-name]

E.g.,

- /collections/shoes
- /collections/tshirts
- /collections/hats
  etc

Product pages follow this structure: /collections/[collection-name]/products/[product-name]

E.g.,

- /collections/shoes/products/pink-reeboks
- /collections/tshirts/products/plain-white-tee

So I want to capture just the collection pages but not the product pages.

I have already identified a negative lookahead as the ideal way to do this. However, Google Analytics **does not allow negative lookaheads**, so I need another way to do this. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you do `^/collections/collection-\d$`

Comment: Hi Blexy.  That won't work because the collections are all named collection-1 collection-2. I was just using those as examples.  It's more like shoes, hats, tshirts, pants, etc.  I've changed the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ranges `[a-zA-Z0-9]` this won't match a `\`. See [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/vnPpk76iMp) for a simple demo of this regex.

```
^/collections/[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Of course you need to update your regex if you use [collection tags](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/subcategories) within Shopify.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! The only thing that your answer missed is that the urls contain hyphens. E.g. /collections/reebok-shoes
I just used ^/collections/([a-zA-Z0-9]|-)*$  although feel free to suggest a more elegant way of doing this.  Thank you again!